# constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type

Tags: scala

I am using Scala 2.11.8

I have this code

```
val i1 = Either[ErrorCode, Person] = getMaybePerson().toRight(ErrorCode.NOTFOUND)
val i2 = Either[ErrorCode, (Int, FiniteDuration)] = getMaybeConfig().toRight(ErrorCode.NOCONFIG)
for {
   a <- i1.right
   (c, d) <- i2.right
} yield {...}
```

The IDE (IntelliJ 2017.1) does not show any errors. but when I compile from SBT. it says

```
Warning:(163, 43) `withFilter' method does not yet exist on scala.util.Either.RightProjection[ErrorCode,(Int, scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration)], using `filter' method instead
     (maxReward, checkDuration) <- i2.right
Error:(163, 10) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: scala.util.Either[Nothing,(Int, scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration)]
         (maxReward, checkDuration) <- i2.right
```

This is driving me nuts, because In the REPL. I can easily write this code.

```
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_121).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
defined class Person

scala> val x = Some(Person("foo", 20))
x: Some[Person] = Some(Person(foo,20))

scala> val y = Some(("foo", 20))
y: Some[(String, Int)] = Some((foo,20))

scala> for {
     | a <- x.toRight("wrong").right
     | b <- y.toRight("wrong").right
     | } yield (a.name, a.age, b._1, b._2)
res0: scala.util.Either[String,(String, Int, String, Int)] = Right((foo,20,foo,20))

scala>
```

Comment: Double check the classpath, make sure there is no version pollution going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that `Either` does not sit well with for comprehensions (at least in scala <2.11).

So you first have to remember that for comprehensions are syntactic sugar for monadic operations `map`, `flatMap`, and `withFilter`.

In particular, when doing pattern matching on an extracted value (such as the `(c, d) <- i2.right` in your code), this is replaced by (something equivalent to)

```
i2.right.withFilter(_.isInstanceOf[Tuple2[A, B]]).map{p =>
  val (c, d) = p.asInstanceOf[Tuple2[A, B]]
  ...
}
```

Now you may see more clearly what the problem is: first, there is no `withFilter` method on `RightProjection`, so it uses `filter` instead (as the error statement says). Then the `filter` method outputs an `Option[Either[ErrorCode, (Int, FiniteDuration)]]`, so you cannot pattern match with a tuple against it.

If you can get around the `filter` problem, you will probably come against the problem with `map` (I know I did):
If you try using an assignment in for comprehension:

```
for {
  a <- Right("foo").right
  b = a + "bar"
} yield a + b
```

This won't work either, because it is replaced by a `map` call on an `Either`... but since `Either` is not right-biased (or left-), it does not have a `map` method, so the compiler will be lost (and give you some confusing error message, if you don't think about how the `for` is desugared).

In general, you should avoid using `Either` in for comprehension if you want to do some filtering (pattern matching included) or assignements. You might want to consider some equivalent monads in some libs, such as `Validation` or `\/` in catz or scalaz.

**NB** I said something about scala 2.11, because in scala 2.12, `Either` becomes right-biased, so some of the afore-mentioned problems disappear, but I haven't tried my hands on it yet.